# Centering button in css

Tags: html, css, button

I am making a mock website as I learn to code and I cannot figure out how to center my "View my Work" button in CSS. I have looked at other issues people were having with this on Stack Overflow and I have tried wrapping it in a div and I have tried using input[type="button"] but still not getting anywhere.The second option allows me to move the button a little bit to the right but then stops and I can't get it all the way in the center.

The issue is at maximum screen width (@media screen and (min-width: 992px)).

A second issue I am having is that I want my background picture to have the opacity but not the heading and text in button on top of it. I do not know how to stop the opacity in the text. Thanks guys!

Here is the HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <title> Sankyeat Kumar | Web Developer </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <div><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
        <div><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></div>
        <div><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></div>
        <div><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></div>
    </div>

    <div id="banner">
        <div id="heading">
            <h1> Sankyeat Kumar</h1>
            <h4>London Based Web Developer For Hire</h4>
        </div>  

        <div id="button">
            <input type="button" value="View My Work" class="portfolio">
        </div>

    </div>




    <div id="section-a">
        <h2> Services </h2>

        <div id="services">
            <div class="sections">
                <h3>Web Design</h3>
                <p class="section-para">Freelance-Creator offers an exceptional variety of web design services to suit everybody, whether you're self employed or a small business, I can come up with a quality website to suit your needs. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="sections">
                <h3>Responsive Web Sites </h3>
                <p class="section-para">With everybody on the go with mobile & tablet devices it is important to make sure your website is accesible on the go. Responsive websites are also a cheaper alternative to a phone app! </p>
            </div>
            <div class="sections">
                <h3>SEO & Marketing </h3>
                <p class="section-para">SEO (Search Engine Optimisation) is important when it comes to creating an online presence for your website. We offer simple, cost effective and proven marketing results to all of our clients. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="sections">
                <h3>CMS Solutions</h3>
                <p class="section-para">Take full control of your website, whether it be a simple text modification, to an image upload or to adding 100's of products, we will find the right CMS solution for you, that is simple and user friendly. </p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <h2>Contact me</h2>
        <form action="/action_page.php">

            <label for="fname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

            <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

            <label for="country">Country</label>
            <select id="country" name="country">
                <option value="australia">Australia</option>
                <option value="canada">Canada</option>
                <option value="usa">USA</option>
            </select>

            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        </form>
    </div>

    </div>  

</body>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
body {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
#menu {
    display:flex;
    background-color: black;
    max-height:50px;
    max-width:100%;
}

#menu div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: ##678F99;
    padding:10px;
}

#menu div a {
    color:white;    
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#menu div a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#banner {
    height:100vh;
    width:100%;

}

#heading {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}

#banner #heading h1 {
    color:black;
    font-size: 4em;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}

#banner #heading h4 {
    color:black;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 0 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.portfolio {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: relative;
    left: 143px;
}

#heading h4 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    bottom:50px;
}

#section-a > h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#section-a {
    background-color: #5F5F5F;
}

#section-a h2 {
    color:white;
}

#services {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    color: white;
}

.sections {
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.sections h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

.section-para {
    text-align: justify;
}

input[type=text], select, textarea {
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    padding: 12px; /* Some padding */  
    border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Gray border */
    border-radius: 4px; /* Rounded borders */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Make sure that padding and width stays in place */
    margin-top: 6px; /* Add a top margin */
    margin-bottom: 16px; /* Bottom margin */
    resize: vertical /* Allow the user to vertically resize the textarea (not horizontally) */
}

    /* Style the submit button with a specific background color etc */
    input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* When moving the mouse over the submit button, add a darker green color */
input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

/* Add a background color and some padding around the form */
.container {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

}

```
only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
```

}

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {

#menu {
    display:flex;
    background-color: black;
    max-height:50px;
    max-width:100%;
}

#menu div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: ##678F99;
    padding:10px;
}

#menu div a {
    color:white;    
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#menu div a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#banner {
    height:100vh;
    width:100%;
    background-image: url('images/london.jpg');
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 0;

}

#heading {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}

#banner #heading h1 {
    color:black;
    font-size: 5em;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    z-index: 1;
}

#banner #heading h4 {
    color:black;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 0 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

.portfolio {
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

}

input[type="button"] {
    position:relative;
    right:350px;
}

#heading h4 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    bottom:50px;
}

#section-a {
    margin-top: -33px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#section-a > h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

#services {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.sections {
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
}

.sections h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

.section-para {
    text-align: justify;
}

.container {
    margin-top: -80px;
}

input[type=text], select, textarea {
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    padding: 12px; /* Some padding */  
    border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Gray border */
    border-radius: 4px; /* Rounded borders */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Make sure that padding and width stays in 
place */
    margin-top: 6px; /* Add a top margin */
    margin-bottom: 16px; /* Bottom margin */
    resize: vertical /* Allow the user to vertically resize the textarea 
(not horizontally) */
}

/* Style the submit button with a specific background color etc */
input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* When moving the mouse over the submit button, add a darker green color */
input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

/* Add a background color and some padding around the form */
.container {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you clean up this question? We don't need all your code. If you can isolate the exact HTML/css pairing that is giving you trouble (and even better, provide a link to codepen.io or some other live editor), it will make it much easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

you should try setting the following property for the button

```
display:inline-block;
position:static
margin-auto;
```

and don't forget to set it's parent width to 100%;

**Hope It Helps**

Comment: Happy that I could help you :D :D. Shouldn't you mark it as the expedted answer so that other users who have the same problem can find it easily?